# Need to clear CMOS to then be sent recover BIOS setting, to then be allowed to boot

Tags: boot, bios, cmos

As the title says every time I shut down the computer I need to clear the CMOS with a built in button on the RAMPAGE V EXTREME. I then get sent to a page which tells me to enter setup to recover BIOS setting. I will then be sent to he BIOS where I can select the SSD to boot from and start using the computer. If I do not clear the CMOS the computer will turn on, but the screen will show nothing, it will just be black. I have tried with multiple screens, using HDMI, Display port and DVI. Someone else have posted the same question a long time ago. I have tried to update the BIOS, swap RAM and I highly doubt it have anything to do with the onboard battery as the computer is only 3 years old(I have also tried to change it). It is a work computer which have been stored away for a while, but I was assured that it worked before I got it.

Comment: Have you actually tried replacing the battery? Costs mere pennies but rules out a defective battery. Age doesn't really matter, I've had a motherboard once that needed a new one every couple years.

Comment: I have tested it now, but no change. I will edit my question.